# Mongoid has_and_belongs_to_many inverse_of: :nil unexpected data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a collection of Tasks that relate back to themselfs

```
class Task
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :related_tasks , class_name: 'Task', inverse_of: :nil
```

In the monogo data I am looking for
Parent task

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId(""),
"related_task_ids" : [
    ObjectId(""),
    ObjectId("")
],
}
```

And on the child task (nothing)

The parent tasks looks correct.
But on the child task I get

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId(""),
"nil_ids" : [
    ObjectId("")
],
"related_task_ids" : [ ],
}
```

Where `nil_ids` is the parent id.

Why is it storing the nil_id's? and is there any way to stop this?

I want a 1..n relationship i.e a task has many children.

It's not a n..n relationship i.e. Children tasks don't have many parent tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are seeing a `nil_ids` key on the child side of the association is that you have specified the `:nil` Ruby symbol rather than `nil`. So Mongoid is just interpreting this like any other symbol and creating a `nils` collection on the `Task` as the inverse of the `related_tasks` collection.

Try:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :related_tasks , class_name: 'Task', inverse_of: nil
```

This should leave the `related_task_ids` in the parent task but not store the `nil_ids` on the children.